# Break up long line of text in Java or Scala

Tags: java, scala, word-wrap

I have a `String longLineOfWords`, that I want to break up into several lines (`List<String> severalShortLinesOfWords`, or similar).

Whether a line is too long, and should therefore be broken up, is determined by the following function:

```
private def isLineTooLong(line: String): Boolean = {
  val bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
  val graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics

  val metrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(font)

  metrics.stringWidth(line) > imgWidth
}
```

This is difficult programming for me. Can someone help me?

Comment: Aka: your professor told you to create a method `isLineTooLong()` to split a string. We don't do coderequests, please show what you have so far.

Comment: how do you make the difference between a line that is long enough to be broken and a line which should not be?

Comment: Wouldn't that be `isLineTooLong(String)`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I realize that the question is not explained enough. Give me a moment to rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of the `isLineTooLong` method doesn't affect how you would solve this.

What you need to do is:

1. Split the line into words.
2. Create an empty list.
3. Start with an empty string `s`
4. Repeatedly add a word to `s` until it gets too long or you run out of words
5. Backtrack one word - use the previous line before you added a word, and add that to the result list. Push the word you didn't use back onto the collection of words!
6. Repeat this process from step 3 until you have no more words
7. Very important: display the resulting list on the screen, to check that it looks approximately correct.

This is known as *word-wrapping*. In fact what you will be doing is word-wrapping the text for display by the default font (note: this may not be a fixed-width font, so the result you get if printing it out in a terminal in a fixed-width font may be more jagged than you expect).

To implement the above algorithm in Scala, you can use either recursion, iteration or recursion schemes such as fold and unfold. Use whichever you prefer. You could also implement it in Java using recursion or iteration.

By the way, you could make `isLineTooLong` more efficient by doing what I call "manual partial evaluation", and reducing the image size, like this:

```
private val isLineTooLong: String => Boolean = {
  val bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
  val graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics

  val metrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(font)

  (line: String) => metrics.stringWidth(line) > imgWidth
}
```

The only downside of this optimisation is that the `BufferedImage` and the associated objects referenced inside there will not be garbage collected until `isLineTooLong` is itself garbage collected (which may be never, depending on where you put it).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was thinking the wrong way I think, namely stripping words from the long string until it's not too long. I'll give a shot at your suggestion right now

Comment: By the way: for future questions of this nature, it is better to ask for help in writing an *algorithm*. Using this magic word may reduce hostility and close votes :)

Comment: By the way, I'm not required to use that method. And it's not an assignment. I want to display lines of text over an image, and need to word-wrap those lines if they exceed the image width. If you think that the implementation of `isLineTooLong` can be improved, I'm interested

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by the comment on the question which guessed that it was an assignment.

Comment: Thanks once more, for the suggestion on how to improve `isLineTooLong`

Answer (score 0):

I slapped the following together quickly so you can reason about the logic. I wouldn't use this as a final answer because it still leaves " inside of it, but it should get you started.

And this is wrapping a string into a list of strings. Each cell contains the number of characters given to the function. So it's wrapping by char length not # of words per line.

```
object Extra1 {
  val zs = "Perform Word Wrapping by a set line length over a list"
                                                  //> zs  : String = Perform Word Wrapping by a set line length over a list
  Format(zs, 5)                                   //> res0: List[String] = List(Perfo, rm Wo, rd Wr, appin, "g by ", a set, " line
                                                  //| ", " leng", th ov, "er a ", list)
}


object Format {
  def apply(line: String, n: Int): List[String] = {
    val chars = line.toList
    def loop(words: List[Char], acc: List[Char], facc: List[String]): List[String] = words match {
      case Nil => acc.mkString.reverse :: facc
      case x if(acc.length >= n) => loop(x, List[Char](), (acc.mkString).reverse :: facc)
      case char::xs => loop(xs, char :: acc, facc)//(xs, (char.toString ++ acc))
    }
    loop(chars, List[Char](), List[String]()).reverse
  }
}
```